# VSCode Python region doesn't work in all cases

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to write Python code. I'd like to use `#region foo` and `#endregion foo` to provide custom folding. This sometimes works. When I say sometimes I mean it works for some instances but not others.

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_advanced_function_call_count(myfile, monkeypatch, mocker):
    # region setup
    monkeypatch.setattr(myfile, 'basic_function', Mock())
    # endregion setup
    
    # region execution
    myfile.advanced_function2()
    assert myfile.basic_function.call_count == 1
    # endregion execution
```

In the above example I can fold `# region setup` but I can't fold `# region execution`. In my real code there doesn't appear to be a pattern of it only folding one region, the first region, or the last region. It appears to be random.

Any ideas what is preventing random regions from being able to fold?

Comment: They both work for me when I copied your code.  Might be an some extension interfering.

Comment: I've disabled all extensions in the current workspace. Issue remains. Some regions fold, some don't.

Comment: That is very weird.  You might try `#region` and `#endregion` (without the spaces) just to see if it makes any difference.  It shouldn't though.

Comment: It doesn't. I've tried variations of capitol letters and spaces as well.

Comment: I encountered the same problem in vscode. I think it seems to be a bug. I submitted it to [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19829). By the way, @Markm are you using the latest version of vscode and python extensions

Comment: Something I found out is if the `# endregion` is after the last line of code in a def then it's not valid. This seems kindof like a scoping issue. A "workaround" is to put `pass` after the endregion but that's ugly, doesn't cleanly fold, and muddies the intent of the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3290#issuecomment-1242654484) in github.

This should be caused by overlapping folding areas (`def` itself has a hidden fold). Take your code as an example:

```
def test_advanced_function_call_count(myfile, monkeypatch, mocker):  #region A start
    # region setup                                                   #region B start
    monkeypatch.setattr(myfile, 'basic_function', Mock())
    # endregion setup                                                #region B end
    
    # region execution                                               #region C start
    myfile.advanced_function2()
    assert myfile.basic_function.call_count == 1                     #region A end
    # endregion execution                                            #region C end
```

The inclusion relationship between region A and region B can be allowed:

```
# Range A start
  # Range B start
  # Range B end
# Range A end
```

> Something I found out is if the # endregion is after the last line of code in a def then it's not valid.

However, there is a staggered inclusion relationship between A and C, which leads to the failure of C folding:

```
# Range A start
  # Range C start
# Range A end
  # Range C end
```